# Python random array prints chosen variables

Tags: python, random

The goal is to make an array of 10 random numbers from 10 to 95.

Then only print the numbers which are greater than 40.

I've made a very simple part, there's probably a better way but I'm not sure how to make python chose which numbers are greater than 40 after having my random array:

```
import random

mm = list(range(10,96))
print(random.choice(mm),random.choice(mm), random.choice(mm), 
random.choice(mm), random.choice(mm), random.choice(mm), 
random.choice(mm),random.choice(mm), random.choice(mm), random.choice(mm))
```

Comment: Did you try `[x for x in random.sample(mm, k=10) if x > 40]`?

Comment: I'm relatively new to python; could u explain how it works?

Comment: @coldspeed Ive changed it to: import random; 
mm = list(range(10,96)); 
x = random.sample(mm,k=10); 
print(x);   however when I tried using '> 40' it doesn't allow it as it's a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of repeating `random.choice` multiple times, you can use `random.choices` and provide `k=10` as argument. A list comprehension then allows to keep only numbers greater than `40`.

```
import random

# Pick 10 random numbers with replacement
numbers = random.choices(range(10, 96), k=10)

# Filter out numbers <= 40
numbers_above_40 = [x for x in numbers if x > 40]

print(numbers_above_40) # [54, 77, 60, 75, 70, 90, 75, 44]
```

If you want to randomly pick numbers *without replacement* use `random.sample` instead.